# Is using COUNT(*) or SELECT * a good idea?

Tags: sql, database

I've heard several times that you shouldn't perform `COUNT(*)` or `SELECT *` for performance reasons, but wasn't able to dig up some further information about it.

I can imagine that the database is then using *all* columns for the action, which can be an impressive performance loss, but I'm not sure about that. Does somebody have further information about the topic?

Comment: Some database engines will optimize a `COUNT(*)` by using an index because the actual values in the columns are ignored.

Comment: [Interesting Article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/adviceoncount/808/)

Comment: One thing that I would never use is `SELECT *` in a `Stored Procedure`.  Many times I have had to figure out why my code is broken and it's because the database is now returning a new column.

Comment: @Gabe: nearly right: ...by using the PK because....it makes a difference !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### 1. On count(*) vs. count(something else)

SQL is declarative in that you specify *what* you want. This is different from specifying *how* to get what you want. That means the database engine is free to realize your query in whatever way it thinks is the most efficient. Many database optimizers rewrites your query to a less costly alternative (if such a plan is available).

Given the following table:

```
table(
   pk       not null
  ,color    not null
  ,nullable null
  ,unique(pk)
  ,index(color)
);
```

...**all** of the following are functionally equivalent (due to the mechanics of **count** and **nulls**):

```
1) select count(*) from table;
2) select count(1) from table;
3) select count(pk) from table;
4) select count(color) from table;
```

Regardless of which form you use, the optimizer is free to rewrite the query to another form if it is more efficient. (Again, not all optimizers are sophisticated enough to do this). The unique index(pk) would be smaller (bytes occupied) than the entire table. Therefore it would be more efficient to count the number of index entries rather than scanning through the entire table. In Oracle we have bitmap indexes, which also compress repeating strings. If we had used such an index on the color column, it would probably have been the smallest index to scan. Oracle also supports table compression which in some cases makes the physical table smaller than a composite index.

**1. TL;DR;**
Your specific dbms will have its own set of tools that enables different rewriting rules and in turn execution plans. That renders the question somewhat useless (unless we talk about a specific release of a specific dbms). I recommend `COUNT(*)` in all cases because it requires the least cognitive effort to grasp.

### 2. On select a,b,c vs. select *

There are very few valid uses of `SELECT *` in code **you** write and put into production. Imagine a table which contains Bluray movies (yes, the movies is stored as a blob in this table). So you slapped together your awesomesauce abstraction layer and put `SELECT * FROM movies where id = ?` in the `getMovies(movie_id)` method. I will refrain myself from explaining why `SELECT name FROM movies` will be transported across the network just a tad faster. Of course, in most realistic cases it won't have a noticable impact.

One last point on performance is that when all the referenced columns (selected, filtered) in your query exists as an index (called a covering index), the database need not touch the table at all. It can be fully resolved from scanning the index only. By selecting all columns you remove this option from the optimizer.

Another thing about `SELECT *` which is far more serious than anything, is that it creates an implicit dependency on a specific physical layout of the table. Let me explain. Consider the following tables:

```
table T1(name, id)
table T2(name, id)
```

The following statement...

```
insert into t1 select * from t2;
```

... will break or produce a different result if any of the following happens:

- Any of the tables columns are rearranged for example T1(id, name)
- T1 gets an additional not-null column
- T2 gets another column

**2. TL;DR;** When possible, explicitly specify the columns you want (eventually, you'll have to do that anyway). Also, selecting fewer columns are faster than selecting more columns. A possitive side-effect on explicit selects is that it gives greater freedom to the optimizer.

Comment: The `insert into t1 select * from t2` actually looks to my eye like a good use for `select *` iff the two tables are required for other reasons to be formatted identically.  Your 'breaking conditions' should say "T1 gets a non-null column *and T2 does not*" and "T2 gets another column *and T1 does not*.  It will correctly handle the case where the same column gets added to both tables, whereas code which explicitly listed the columns to use would break.

Answer (score 7):

`COUNT(*)` is different from `COUNT(column1)` !
`COUNT(*)` returns the number of records, and does NOT use more resources, while `COUNT(column1)` counts the number of records where column1 is non null.

For `SELECT`, it is different. `SELECT *` will of course request more data.

Answer (score 3):

When using `count(*)` the `*` doesn't mean "all fields". Using `count(field)` will count all non-null values in the field, but `count(*)` will always count all records even if all fields in all records are null, so it doesn't need to check the data in the fields at all.

Using `select *` means that you almost always return more data than you are going to use, which of course is a waste. However, perhaps more serious is the maintainence problem; if you add fields to a table your query will return these too. That might mean that the record becomes too large to fit in the buffer, resulting in an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse the * in "COUNT(*)" with the * in "SELECT * ". They are completely unrelated but sometimes confused because it's such an odd syntax. There is nothing wrong with using COUNT(*), which just means "count rows".

SELECT * on the other hand means "select all columns". That's generally poor practice because it tightly couples your code to the database schema. That means when you change the table you probably have to change the code even if it should have been unaffected. It increases the impact of any schema change.

SELECT * may also cause a sub-optimal query plan. Either because you didn't really need all columns or because it forces the DBMS to do an extra lookup at runtime to get the list of columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely true that "*" is "all columns". And you're right in the point of if you've a table with an incredible number of columns (say 100+), these kind of queries can be bad in terms of efficiency.

I believe that the best solution is creating database views previously filtering the amount of records evolved in the count operation, so, the performance impact isn't a big problem, because views can be cached.

In the other hand, it seems that "*" operator should be avoided when returning records, and it's brutally better to select the fields you really need to use in some business.

Answer (score 0):

When using `SELECT *` it can have a performance hit. Applications which use the `SELECT *` syntax when they actually only need a handful of columns are transferring more data across the network than they need to consume, which is wasteful.

Also, in Microsoft SQL Server at least, there's a strange problem when you use `SELECT *` in a view and then add a column to the underlying table. The column headings and data returned by the view don't match each other following certain changes! See [my blog post](http://www.richardfawcett.net/2010/09/20/why-i-never-use-select-from/) for further details of this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `COUNT(*)` it **depends** on database and its version. For example in modern versions of `MS SQL` it doesn't matter [source needed].

So the best approach in case of `COUNT(*)` is to measure it.

Using `SELECT *` is really bad idea. `*` means *read all columns* which can be heavy IO and network operation (especially for various type of `CHAR` columns). Moreover -- rather rarely you need all columns.

Comment: Tip: If you **emphasise** almost **every** *word* it **loses** it's **meaning**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the database depends on how inefficient it becomes, the simnplest way to describe would be like so:

when you specifically do:

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM table1
```

Mysql knows exactly exactly what columns it looking for, but when you do

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Mysql does not know the columns you want, it knows you want all of them but not the names, so it has to perform extra tasks that analyse the table to discover the columns, thus resulting in using resources.