# Insert into with a sub select * not working

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

If Table A and B have identical structures (except ID field). In A its autoassigned, but in B it is expecting the value from an insert.

How can I do a INSERT INTO A (select * from B).

What is the quickest, most flexible SQL that can run in a stored proc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the columns explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TableB
```

Comment: Select * in general should not be used in production code. In this case, it cannot be used.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need to hire a secretary to type in all the column names :)

Comment: @HLGEM, I've seen plenty of select * in production systems. I don't see any reason to out rule its use in production. Granted I'm not a DBA, but * seems to get all fields, not sure why this would be frowned on in production environments.

Comment: JL, it is a problem for many reasons, first it creates maintenance problems where columns are added and the application can't handle them properly or worse where columns are added that the users should not see and they are exposed. If some incompetent recreates the table with the columns in a differnt order, then reporting, etc can break because the columns don't have the right data. There are problems with views when the structure changes and most important it is wasteful of resources to provide columns you don't need.  It is a bad practice.

Comment: Was running out of room, but you don't ever need to type columns, just drag them over from the object browser. There is no excuse to be too lazy to type colummns.

Comment: @JL: About * in production, [see earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437399/is-using-count-or-select-a-good-idea/4439459#4439459)

Comment: @HLGEM, yeah it makes sense - I guess people could be using reader objects based on field index (0),(1), etc - in this case select * only works in original scenario. Thanks for info!