# What is the most efficient way to count rows in a table in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've always just used "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM X" but perhaps this is not the most efficient.  Any thoughts?  Other options include SELECT COUNT(*) or perhaps getting the last inserted id if it is auto-incremented (and never deleted).

How about if I just want to know if there is anything in the table at all?  (e.g., count > 0?)

Comment: For count(*) vs count(something else), have a look (here) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437399/is-using-count-or-select-a-good-idea/4439459#4439459]

Comment: `expo-sqlite-orm` sidenote - this is offtopic to OP, but I found this while looking why count wasn't working - it's because the library is filtering all results (even count) by defined model columns, workaround is to use alias of a known column e.g. `SELECT COUNT(X) as id` if you have an `id` column on your model.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way is to make sure that you run `SELECT COUNT` on a single column (`SELECT COUNT(*)` is slower) - but `SELECT COUNT` will always be the fastest way to get a count of things (the database optimizes the query internally).

If you check out the comments below, you can see arguments for why `SELECT COUNT(1)` is probably your best option.

Comment: It is even better if you select count(columnName) on a column that is indexed on the table.

Comment: So not SELECT COUNT(1) but SELECT COUNT(id)?

Comment: @Luke, @dwb: can you prove that? COUNT(1) is the same as COUNT(X) (as per [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)) because 1 is not-null. COUNT(*) is the same. It will choose any index.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) does *not* mean "count all the columns".  It means count any row.  It is semantically the same as SELECT COUNT(any non-NULL constant value).  It is not related to SELECT *.

Comment: This is wrong.  SELECT COUNT(column) does not provide the same possibility for optimization as SELECT COUNT(non-NULL constant).  In the later case no table or index scan is necessary; it's sufficient to return the number of rows, or number of entries in the primary key index.

Comment: I've just checked it on my DB and `count(*)` works 4 times faster than `count(1)` and 7 times faster than `count(indexed_column)` in my case. So the answer is just not true... I use sqlite 3.31.1

Comment: for me count(_ROWID_) works much faster than count(*) on a table with 10's of millions of rows and just 2 columns

Answer (score 9):

To follow up on girasquid's answer, as a data point, I have a sqlite table with 2.3 million rows. Using `select count(*) from table`, it took over 3 seconds to count the rows. I also tried using `SELECT count(rowid) FROM table`, (thinking that rowid is a default primary indexed key) but that was no faster. Then I made an index on one of the fields in the database (just an arbitrary field, but I chose an integer field because I knew from past experience that indexes on short fields can be very fast, I think because the index is stored a copy of the value in the index itself). `SELECT count(my_short_field) FROM table` brought the time down to less than a second.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `select count(rowid) from table` or `select count(my_short_field) from table`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure (really sure) that you've never deleted any row from that table and your table has not been defined with the WITHOUT ROWID optimization you can have the number of rows by calling:

```
select max(RowId) from table;
```

Or if your table is a circular queue you could use something like

```
select MaxRowId - MinRowId + 1 from
  (select max(RowId) as MaxRowId from table) JOIN
  (select min(RowId) as MinRowId from table);
```

This is really really fast (milliseconds), but you must pay attention because sqlite says that row id is unique among all rows in the same table. SQLite does not declare that the row ids are and will be always consecutive numbers.

Comment: Here you can read something about relying on rowid [link](http://www.sqlabs.com/blog/2010/12/sqlite-and-unique-rowid-something-you-really-need-to-know/)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get row counts is directly from the table metadata, if any.  Unfortunately, I can't find a reference for this kind of data being available in SQLite.

Failing that, any query of the type

SELECT COUNT(non-NULL constant value) FROM table

should optimize to avoid the need for a table, or even an index, scan.  Ideally the engine will simply return the current number of rows known to be in the table from internal metadata.   Failing that, it simply needs to know the number of entries in the index of any non-NULL column (the primary key index being the first place to look).

As soon as you introduce a column into the SELECT COUNT you are asking the engine to perform at least an index scan and possibly a table scan, and that will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will find a special method for this.  However, you could do your select count on the primary key to be a little bit faster.

Answer (score -3):

`sp_spaceused 'table_name'`  (exclude single quote)

this will return the number of rows in the above table, this is the most efficient way i have come across yet.

it's more efficient than `select Count(1) from 'table_name'` (exclude single quote)

`sp_spaceused` can be used for any table, it's very helpful when the table is exceptionally big (hundreds of millions of rows), returns number of rows right a way, whereas `'select Count(1)'` might take more than 10 seconds. Moreover, it does not need any column names/key field to consider.

Comment: The question is about SQLite, not SQL Server