# Using EXISTS in hibernate to return one row only for performance(without setMaxResult)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have to print a message if ANY duplicate row with same ID (not a primary KEY) exists in table (very large table), that meets a where clause.

Table Person is (There is no Index on table)

```
PersonPrimaryKEY    PersonName      ID      Email             Address      InvoiceID  TaxID
       1             Bob             1       bob@example.com   1/Harton st   1        1
       2             John            2       john@example.com  2/Harton st   2        2
       3             Peter           1123    peter@example.com 3/Harton st   3        3
```

I used hibernate

```
public Collection<Person> readByNameAndID (String name, String ID)
{
    TypedQuery<Person> q = getEntityManager ().createNamedQuery("Select p FROM Person p WHERE Name =:Name AND ID <> :ID", Person.class);
    q.setParameter ("Name", Name);
    q.setParameter ("ID", ID);
    return q.getResultList ();
}
```

Code to use is

```
if(results.size > 0)
{
   System.out.println("Error exists");
}
```

Problem is, it is very inefficient when reading large table.

How can I make it very efficient ? I was thinking of using EXISTS or COUNT to do that but how to incorporate it with hibernate so that it returns only ONE row then I check size > 0, which will be efficient.

Or is setMaxResult only solution of that ?

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: Can we do like this ? SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM PERSON
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME    = 'A' AND ID <> '1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are considering records duplicate on the basis of having the same `PersonName`, the following HQL query should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(p)
FROM Person p
GROUP BY p.PersonName
HAVING COUNT(p) > 1
```

If the count from this query is greater than 0, it means you have duplicates present.

Comment: Thanks a lot for information. One thing, can we make COUNT(\*) more efficient ? As COUNT(\*) will parse all the table to get the total count. Is there any technique to use EXISTS etc because we just have to check duplicate, even if a SINGLE ROW exists with same ID, we return the query and give error, no need to parse all

Comment: There is no way to avoid counting all the rows.  However, using `COUNT(1)` appears to be an efficient way, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474873/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-count-rows-in-a-table-in-sqlite) for more information.

Comment: I think you are exactly right. One last thing, why are we not using EXISTS to check for single existence of the duplicate row ? I heard EXISTS is much faster because, it will not parse the whole table but will return when it find first row meeting the condition ? After this, I will mark this question as answered :)

Comment: What are the columns in the `Person` table?

Comment: It is Name and ID and many other columns like 10 other e.g. email, address. There is NOT any index on ANY column. But have to just check duplicate existence of SAME name with different ID. Means any person, whom I am trying to insert in table, exists who has same name, then show error

Comment: I never really answered your question unfortunately.  Please update your question with all columns in the `Person` table, thanks.

Comment: One last question: For a pair of duplicate records, would all columns be identical except for the `PersonPrimaryKEY` ?

Comment: No, they can ALL be different. Name should not be duplicate, before saving to database. ID could be same but Name should not when trying to insert record.

Comment: Thanks. I marked it and answer and use it in code :) Thanks again

Comment: Make sure this works for you.  Your original question pointed me in the wrong direction at first.

Comment: I checked and it does :) Thanks!