# Padding 0's - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, select, datatable, zero-pad

So, I have a column that is my key column and auto-increments, so it can't be varchar or anything fun.

Please hold back the "Erhmahgerd urse werb contrerls" as I like to control my own HTML flow and don't like handing it over to .NET. I've never had good experiences with that (and I like my code to be compliant). I wouldn't like this to be a flame war or anything - I just want to pad with zeroes. I feel the need to say this because it's happened way too many times before.

So, anyway.

```
DataTable tabledata = new DataTable();  
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
    using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM equipment_table", con)) {
        OdbcDataAdapter myAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = com;
        try {
            con.Open();
            myAdapter.Fill(tabledata);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw (ex);
        } finally {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
Response.Write("<table id=\"equipment_listtable\"><thead><tr><th>Equipment ID</th><th>Equipment Name</th><th>Equipment Description</th><th>Type</th><th>In Use?</th><th>iOS Version (if applicable)</th><th>Permission Level</th><th>Status</th><th>Asset Tag</th><th>Details</th><th>Change</th><th>Apply</th></tr></thead>");
foreach (DataRow row in tabledata.Rows) {
    int counter = (int)row["Equipment_ID"];
    Response.Write("<tr>");
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) {
        Response.Write("<td>" + item + "</td>");
    }
    Response.Write("This stuff is irrelevant to my problem, so it is being left out... It uses counter though, so no complaining about not using variables...");
}
Response.Write("</table>");
```

As you can imagine, the value of my key column comes out like so in the generated table:

```
1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
2
21
```

etc. I'd like to fix this with 0 padding. What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to target a SPECIFIC field while I'm generating the table? I've looked into DataRow.Item, but I've always found the MSDN documentation to be a bit difficult to comprehend.

Alternatively, could I SELECT * and then use mysql's lpad on ONE specific field within the *?

Thanks!

Comment: If the column in the table is numeric, then an order by clause should order it correctly and not alphabetically as you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * is generally not a good idea to use. It inevitably causes more problems than the time it saves by writing the query.
This will allow you to use a LPAD on the column.

I was about to suggest using something like:
    Response.Write("" + item.ToString.PadLeft(2, '0')+ "");

But since you are just looping round each item and rendering them all the same way, the above would pad every cell.

So I think your best option is to change your query to specify every column. Then you can pad the field as you want.
Or use an ORDER BY if you are only concerned they aren't being ordered correctly (ie, ordered as chars not ints).

alternatively, create a variable for each cell read from the database and render each seperately.
this will give you more customisation options, should you requite them.

Answer (score 0):

You really should *always* specify your column names explicitly and not use * anyway - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437399/is-using-count-or-select-a-good-idea).

If you insist on using * then just bring the padded value in as another field:

```
SELECT *,LPAD("Equipment_ID", 2, '0') as Equipment_ID_Padded FROM equipment_table
```

Remember `LPAD` will truncate if your Equipment_ID is longer than 2 digits.

A better solution may be to just pad the values in code using `String.Format` or `ToString("D2");`

```
string paddedString = string.Format("{0:d2}", (int)row["Equipment_ID"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding in C# by using .ToString("D" + number of leading zeros);
eg. if counter = 34 and you call counter.ToString("D5"), you'll get 00034.

If you're using strings, the easiest way would be to convert.toInt32() and then apply the above.

If you'd rather keep using strings, just look into --printf *whups wrong language*-- String.Format.