# How to make SQL Primary key have a specific number of characters?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a MySQL database for shop items. I want these shop items to have IDs like 0001, 0002 etc. But if I use `AUTO_INCREMENT` (which I need) it will go as 1, 2 etc. Is there any way to make `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `PRIMARY KEY` work this way because I need IDs to have a specific number of characters?

This is the code where I'm creating the `items` table:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    discount INT
);
```

This is the Python loop where I'm putting all items from .csv file into the database table:

```
for item in items_list:
    mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO items(name, price, discount) VALUES ({item['name']}, {item['price']}, {item['discount']});")
```

Is it possible to make `AUTO_INCREMENT` work that way or I need to do it manually?

Comment: What database are you using? Have you run this code? What happens?

Comment: You could simply keep the integer AUTO_IMCREMENT and provide a generated column showing the padded value.

Comment: I'm using MySQL database. When I run the code it works but not the way I want it to work. I want the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to set Primary keys to be like 0001, 0002, 0003 etc. and not 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: you can create an view thats returns item.[id] and other columns formated as you like. if you dont want to create an view just format this column in the select statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Padding 0's - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859711/padding-0s-mysql)

Comment: I'd leave your primary key as is, and just add a **generated column** based on your PK with the padded 0's for your users. It will auto calculate and you can even save to disk for optimal performance (faster than just using a view and no need for a new object). Just keep in mind, you are limiting your data to 9,999 values by doing only 4 digits. Not sure you use case, but should keep in mind the max value of your format. See MySQL doc on generated columns here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/#:~:text=MySQL%20provides%20two%20types%20of,above%20is%20a%20virtual%20column.

Comment: okay, thanks @Stephan ! Btw 4 characters in the ID was just an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primary keys need to have one job only, that of uniquely identifying a row. As soon as you start trying to make them look presentable by formatting them or make them sequential without gaps, or even when you try to use them to see if one row was created before another, you create reasons to want to change them.

Practically anything visible to users or involved in business logic  is going to end up needing to change. And primary keys shouldn't change. Changing a primary key means deleting the row and making a new one with the new key value, and also fixing all the references to the old key. It's fiddly and tedious and error-prone, it is something you want to avoid.

Make a separate column for a user-visible identifier separate from the PK that you can have full control over. You can populate it with a trigger or application code based off the key if you want. Just keep it separate from the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Auto_incrememts are tricky, because they can't be used in  BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER it is alays 0

so you need another table and a AFTER INSERT TRIIGGER

> ```
> CREATE TABLE items (
>     item_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
>     discount INT
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>
>     item_id_1 varchar(8) )
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER INSERT ON items
>        FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO  t1 VALUES(LPAD (NEW.item_id , 8, '0'));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO items (name,price, discount) VALUES ('test1',1.1,1)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO items (name,price, discount) VALUES ('test2',1.1,1)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO items (name,price, disc
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
> | item_id_1 |
> | :-------- |
> | 00000001  |
> | 00000002  |
> | 00000003  |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *,(SELECT item_id_1 FROM t1 WHERE item_id_1 + 0 = i.item_id) FROM items i
> ```
>
> ```
> item_id | name  | price | discount | (SELECT item_id_1 FROM t1 WHERE item_id_1 + 0 = i.item_id)
> ------: | :---- | ----: | -------: | :---------------------------------------------------------
>       1 | test1 |  1.10 |        1 | 00000001                                                  
>       2 | test2 |  1.10 |        1 | 00000002                                                  
>       3 | test3 |  1.10 |        1 | 00000003
> ```

> ```
> SELECT i.*,t1.item_id_1 FROM items i JOIN t1 ON i.item_id  = t1.item_id_1 + 0
> ```
>
> ```
> item_id | name  | price | discount | item_id_1
> ------: | :---- | ----: | -------: | :--------
>       1 | test1 |  1.10 |        1 | 00000001 
>       2 | test2 |  1.10 |        1 | 00000002 
>       3 | test3 |  1.10 |        1 | 00000003
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c86138e16601adddb1ce931c838873a1)*

Comment: Can I delete the other table later? And can you explain a bit how is this working?

Comment: Also, how can I make this the way that when I use `SELECT * FROM ` to use the original `items` table and not the `t1`? @nbk

Comment: that depends what you need it for, you ask about how to make a column depending on an auto_increment value, this i provided if you don't need the column for example as reference why do you want a column any way. I added 2 solutions how to access the columsn. the t1 item_id_1 can be a primary key as it is unique.