# count in sql DESC order

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for counting number of replies in one topic,

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM ".prefix."REPLY WHERE TOPIC_ID = '$t' AND R_AUTHOR = '$m' ".$Open_SQL." ") or die(mysql_error());
    $Count = mysql_result($sql, 0, "count(*)");
    if ($Count > 0) {
        $Count = $Count;
    }
    else {
        $Count = "";
    }
return($Count);
mysql_free_result($sql);
}
```

it shows the results fine, what I need is to order this results in DESC.

any suggestions?

Comment: COUNT(*) is usually a heavy operation on any query. Change it to COUNT(yourTableIndex)

Comment: @Bardo Or just use `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: I must be missing something... When you count, order is completely irrelevant. If you have 5 apples, you have 5 apples no matter how you count them.

Comment: The result of `Count` is always a *single* number. the order does not affect the result.

Comment: @Bardo unless you can point at something that proves that, I call [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt).

Comment: You should give us the full query, since we don't know what is the value of `$Open_SQL`. I guess you have some grouping there since you say you get good results.

Comment: @AD7six COUNT(*) makes a count of every full record on the table, which implies the load and management of much more info than counting on a single field. If the table has many fields or contains some complex data types the operation will be much less cost efficient than counting on a single field (an index preferably), or as eisberg stated making a COUNT(1).

Comment: @bardo, the number of _records_ does not change whether you use `count(*)`, `count(1)`, `count(primaryKeyField)` etc. If you are not quoting this from a credible source - I suggest `Explain SELECT count(*) FROM foo` and basing opinion/advice on facts rather than assumptions/rumours.

Comment: @AD7six it seems there's quite discussion in this issue, I supose that could be some database engines today that enables specific performance for count(*), however that's simply because on the SQL standard that structure isn't efficient and database engines had to adjust to what has been a long extended bad practice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437399/is-using-count-or-select-a-good-idea?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: However I think we're discussing too much out of the question scope.

Answer (score 2):

You are just selecting `Count(*)` which means there is nothing to sort, because you will exactly get ONE dataRow, containing the `count`.

What you probably want to do is to add a `GROUP BY`-clause and select different Stuff and order it by count:

```
table
user | type
1      apple
2      apple
3      cherry
```

With such a table, you can group by type and sort the cherry/apple count later.

`SELECT count(*) AS c, type FROM table GROUP BY type ORDER by c DESC/ASC`

Result:

```
c | type
2   apple
1   cherry
```

But without `GROUP BY` it would just return the total count: `3` - no sorting possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to do something like this

```
SELECT some-field, count(*) as count 
FROM your-table
WHERE your-clauses
AND more-clauses
GROUP BY some-field
ORDER BY some-field desc
```